# Enforce pure virtual function implementation, perhaps with different argument type

Tags: c++, c++11, inheritance, polymorphism, system-design

I currently have a Base Class Env, which is an interface, and I have several derived classes.

```
class Env

{
    public:

        //method in question
        virtual std::tuple<Eigen::VectorXf,float,bool,std::string> step(const //what goes here?//)=0;

        virtual ~Env(); //virtual destructor
};
```

An example derived class is as follows (header)

```
class MountainCar: public Env

{
    public:

        MountainCar();
        std::tuple<VectorXf,float,bool,std::string> step(const int) override;

};
```

Now, the design is that all the environments must inherit from Env. However, I want to enforce all the environments to implement the step() method, which is why the step method in the base Env is a pure virtual.

However, each derived Env can take different argument types in the step method, and this should be a valid override (these valid types are from a fixed, known set) Example, mountain car defines it with an int argument. Another Environment, CartPole, takes a VectorXf as the step argument.

Initially, I made the base class a template class with parameter U, and passed U to the step method. Then, the derived classes used to inherit from template instantiations, example MountainCar inherited from Env. However, the issue is that all the derived classes inherit from different instantiations of the base class, and I can no longer use a common base pointer for polymorphism.

How do I design this system with C++11 features?

Comment: How could you use this? If another class had a `std::string` as argument for that method, how would you call the step function using a base pointer?

Comment: Since that class would also inherit from the base class, and the step method is virtual, I could call it. The issue is how to make this possible (make sure the derived class overrides the step method which takes atleast one argument type)

Comment: Thinks about it more. `base->step(something);` in your code. What type of `something` could you pass, if base could point to an env that needs an int there, or something that needs a string?

Comment: I don't understand your point. My base pointer would be Env* MountainCar. Then, I would do Env->step(1).

Comment: If you know the most derived type - sure. But then you don't need a virtual function, just use that derived type. What do you do when you receive and `Env*` as a function argument.

Comment: _"these valid types are from a fixed, known set"_ - please give us a second element from this set, other than `int`.

Comment: If you have a pointer to base and don't know the derived type, then you don't know what argument type to pass the `step` function.  If you have a pointer to base and do know the derived type, then you can convert to the derived type and call a type-safe `step` function.  So do you know the derived type (or the type of the argument) at the point of call?  Second, what else does `Env` do besides provide `step`?  Are you planning on storing some `Env`s somewhere?  Do you store different types of `Env` together, and if so, how do you know which one to call with one argument afterwards?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your premise doesn't make a whole lot of sense. Let's imagine it were possible:

```
class Base {
    virtual void step(/* something */);
};
class DerivedString : public Base {
    void step(std::string) override;
};
class DerivedInt : public Base {
    void step(int) override;
};
```

What would you have this do?

```
std::unique_ptr<Base> bs = std::make_unique<DerivedString>();
bs->step(1);  // compiler error? runtime error?

std::unique_ptr<Base> bi = std::make_unique<DerivedInt>();
bi->step("one");  // compiler error? runtime error?
```

If your answer is "compiler error", then you should drop the virtual functions and the base class, as they're not providing any value.

If your answer is "runtime error" and you have C++17, you can use `std::any`:

```
class Base {
    virtual void step(std::any);
};
class DerivedString : public Base {
    void step(std::any v) override {
        step(std::any_cast<std::string>(v));
    }
    void step(std::string s);
};
class DerivedInt : public Base {
    void step(std::any v) override {
        step(std::any_cast<int>(v));
    }
    void step(int i);
};
```

This will cause `std::bad_any_cast` to be thrown above.

---

If you don't have C++17, and you know the set of types in advance, then you can predeclare every overload of the function:

```
class Base {
    virtual void step(std::string) { throw runtime_error(); }
    virtual void step(int) { throw runtime_error(); }
};
// only subclass from this
template<typename T>
class BaseHelper : public Base {
    void step(T) override = 0; // replace with pure-virtual
}
class DerivedString : public BaseHelper<std::string> {
    void step(std::string s) override;  // compiler error when instantiated if forgotten
};
class DerivedInt : public BaseHelper<int> {
    void step(int i) override;
};
```

Comment: I like the RaiseNotImplemented Error solution, as is common in python, the only issue of it being that we don't get compile time errors. When we have the pure virtual functions, I suppose we would get a compile time error when the step method isn't defined.

Comment: A compilation on `bs->step(1)` is impossible without also creating one on `bi->step(1)`, because `bs` and `bi` have the same type. If they did not have the same type, then you may as well have two different base classes.

Comment: The compilation on the step call is probably impossible, but I was talking about one where the derived class do not implement step at all

Comment: Now, all the derived class have different base classes (since they are template instansiations). What common base pointer do we use now for calling step?

Comment: Keep using `Base`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196504/discussion-between-sridhar-thiagarajan-and-eric).

Answer (score 1):

You define a virtual function **if you want to call it through a base class pointer or reference**. Doing it for any other reason is misuse of the language.

Naturally you can only call a function if you know the signature exactly. If you don't, there can be no call, and no function defined.

So in your case:

```
class Env {
    public:
       virtual 
         std::tuple<Eigen::VectorXf,float,bool,std::string> 
           step(const // What goes here?
                      // The thing YOU want to pass to this function in YOUR code,
                      // if you have an Env pointer or reference:
                      //     pEnv->step(42);
                      // If you don't have a reason to make such a call,
                      // just don't define the function.
               ) = 0;
```

Comment: I do want to call it through the base class pointer. Other than that, I also make it pure virtual to enforce implementation in all derived classes. And for "the thing ... ", what I meant there was I need to be such that despite the derived classes defining this function with a different type, the function override is still valid.

Comment: @SridharThiagarajan *I do want to call it through the base class pointer.* So what type of argument do you want to pass? "Some type" is not a valid answer. You need to name it. If you cannon, think where the value of the argument should come from.

Comment: The argument type will depend on the type of derived object the Base pointer points to. If it's BasePointer* stringclass, a valid input is string etc.

Comment: @SridharThiagarajan *The argument type will depend on the type of derived object the Base pointer points to*. You don't know the type of the derived object. If you knew it, you would use a pointer to the correct derived type instead of a base pointer. The derived type can be created long after you release your code sonin general this is not possible. So where does the argument come from? It is not enough to say "its type will depend on this or that". You need to know the type.

Comment: The type is known to be from a fixed set, if that's helpful

Comment: @SridharThiagarajan So? How do you know which type it will be? *Where does the argument come from?*

Comment: If this helps, pretend compile time types do not exist, everything just works. Can you still make the call? **Show it in your question**.

Comment: @SridharThiagarajan Again, if you *know* the derived type at a location in code, why not call it through the derived type's pointer?  If you *don't know* the derived type, how do you pass it the derived type's argument type?  I understand, you are trying to convert code designed outside of C++ into C++, and in python this is idiomatic.  Doesn't mean it is idiomatic in C++.

Comment: @Adam the reason is that I will have a factory method which returns a base pointer type. So I want to abstract away the derived type from the user. They will know the correct argument to call step with, as that argument is an attribute of the derived type.

Comment: _"as that argument is an attribute of the derived type"_ - but the user doesn't know the derived type either and so can't get that attribute, because the factory function gave them a base type.

Comment: So they will **know** the concrete type (in their head) but still **use** the base type,  right? That's misuse of the type system.

Comment: @Eric, it returns a base pointer type, and I can call a method which returns the type of input